# What is the status of this fifty-year-old conjecture of Kostant?

Tags: reference-request, invariant-theory, homogeneous-spaces, conjectures, reflection-groups

On page 3.27 of his 1963 thesis on the cohomology of homogeneous spaces as approached through the Eilenberg–Moore spectral sequence, Paul Baum states the following conjecture, which he attributes to B. Kostant.

> **Conjecture**. Let $T_\ell$ be a torus in a compact, connected Lie group $G$. Denote the Weyl group of $G$ by $\Phi$ and let $\Phi'$ be the subgroup of $\Phi$
>   consisting of all elements $\varphi \in \Phi$ such that $\varphi(T_\ell) \subset T_\ell$. If
>
> > (i)  the action of $\Phi'$ on $T_\ell$ is crystallographic and
> >
> > (ii) whenever two points of $T_\ell$ are conjugate under $\Phi$ then they are conjugate under $\Phi'$,
>
> then $T_\ell$ is a subgroup of deficiency zero.

Deficiency is an invariant of pairs of compact Lie groups defined by Baum in this thesis; the most common reformulation of the conclusion of the conjecture is probably that

> > (a) The homogeneous space $G/T_\ell$ is formal in the sense of rational homotopy theory.

Some equivalent, purely commutative-algebraic statements of this conclusion are as follows:

> > (b) The cokernel $H^*(BT_\ell;\mathbb Q) \otimes_{H^*(BG;\mathbb Q)} \mathbb{Q}$ is a complete intersection ring, where $H^*(BT_\ell;\mathbb Q)$ is considered a module over $H^*(BG;\mathbb Q)$ through the map $\rho$ functorially induced by $T_\ell \hookrightarrow G$.
> >
> > (c) The ideal $(\rho(I))$ of $H^*(BT_\ell;\mathbb Q)$
> >     generated by the image of the augmentation ideal $I$ of $H^*(BG;\mathbb Q)$
> >     is also generated by a regular subsequence $f_1,\ldots,f_\ell$ in $H^*(BT_\ell;\mathbb Q)$.

The thesis gives no citation for this striking conjecture and it does not appear in the 1967 redaction published in *Topology*. I have been able to find no other reference to it or its potential resolution; perhaps I'm not using the correct search terminology or missing something which would be obvious to someone more versed in Kostant's work.

**Does anyone know the current status of this conjecture? Does anyone know any other reference to it?**

Comment: Why don’t you ask Baum?

Comment: I tried just this a few days before I posted here, but haven't heard back yet. I'll be sure to update this with his response.

Comment: Update: Baum does not remember where or when he heard this conjecture either. A letter (longhand) to Kostant is being written.